# Uniqueness in many-to-many

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I couldn't figure out what terms to google, so help tagging this question or just pointing me in the way of a related question would be helpful.

I believe that I have a typical many-to-many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE elements (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE groups_elements (
  groups_id integer REFERENCES groups,
  elements_id integer REFERENCES elements,
  PRIMARY KEY (groups_id, elements_id));
```

I want to have a constraint that there can only be one groups_id for a given set of elements_ids.

For example, the following is valid:

```
groups_id | elements_id
        1 | 1
        1 | 2
        2 | 2
        2 | 3
```

The following is not valid, because then groups 1 and 2 would be equivalent.

```
groups_id | elements_id
        1 | 1
        1 | 2
        2 | 2
        2 | 1
```

Not every subset of elements must have a group (this is not the power set), but new subsets may be formed.  I suspect that my design is incorrect since I'm really talking about adding a group as a single entity.

How can I create identifiers for subsets of elements without risk of duplicating subsets?

Comment: You could store this as a group_id, membership bitmap, bit n being set would refer to element n. Making this column also unique would give you what you want. You'd probably also want to keep the link table around as it's far more pleasant to join against. You could maintain the link table with triggers. Not sure how many elements this would scale to, though.

Comment: Check this identical question for SQL-Server: **[unique constraint on a set](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/unique-constraint-on-a-set)** This kind of complex requirement would be solved by an `ASSERTION` but no DBMS has implemented those. So, the best solution is probably via triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link from user ypercube was most helpful:  [unique constraint on a set](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/unique-constraint-on-a-set).  In short, a bit of what everyone is saying is correct.

It's a question of tradeoffs, but here are the best options:

a) Add a hash or some other combination of element values to the groups table and make it unique, then populate the groups_elements table off of it using triggers.  Pros of this method are that it preserves querying ability and enforces the constraint so long as you deny naked updates to groups_elements.  Cons are that it adds complexity and you've now introduced logic like "how do you uniquely represent a set of elements" into your database.

b) Leave the tables as-is and control the access to groups_elements with your access layer, be it a stored procedure or otherwise.  This has the advantage of preserving querying ability and keeps the database itself simple.  However, it means that you are moving an analytic constraint into your access layer, which necessarily means that your access layer will need to be more complex.  Another point is that it separates what the data should be from the data itself, which has both pros and cons. If you need faster access to whether or not a set already exists, you can attack that problem separately.

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting problem.

One solution, albeit a klunky one, would be to store a concatenation of groups_id and elements_id in the groups table:   1-1-2 and make it a unique index.

Trying to do a search for duplicate groups before inserting a new row, would be an enormous performance hit.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking too.  For any set of elements, create a sorted group_id_representation 'elem1-elem2-...'.  Then the representation is unique, and you can use that in the groups table (and remove the groups_elements table altogether).

Comment: I also thought of storing a hash of the element IDs but that might be over-engineering it.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would spit out offending group ids:

```
with group_elements_arr as (
    select groups_id, array_agg(elements_id order by elements_id) elements 
    from group_elements 
    group by groups_id )
select elements, count(*), array_agg(groups_id) offending_groups 
    from group_elements_arr 
    group by elements 
    having count(*) > 1;
```

Depending on the size of `group_elements` and its change rate you might get away with stuffing something along this lines into a trigger watching `group_elements`. If that's not fast enough you can materialize `group_elements_arr` into a real table managed by triggers.

And I think, the trigger should be `FOR EACH STATEMENT` and `INITIALLY DEFERRED` for easy building up a new group.